# Diagram with arrows

Tags: diagrams

[image]
Need some help in drawing this 6 vertex diagram, help is much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: this is your third question in short time, where you not show any effort what you try so far ... site doesn't provide service "do-it-for-me".  even more, no one  of received answer you not accept. are all haven't any worth to you?

Comment: I think you managed to draw it just fine. If you want to draw it in TeX however, please show some own effort and if you encounter problems, we'll be glad to help.

Comment: I see 25 vertices; which six of them are you referring to?

Comment: I never knew about this site which is why I have many questions, if I cannot get help here I will just get help otherwise. If I had some indication as to how to draw out one dot with 4 arrows in TeX I'm sure I'll be able to figure out the rest.

Comment: Also I am very new to this, and I am actually very proud of what I have already produced.

Comment: My comment was in no way meant to offend you, but you should always show some own effort in this kind of questions, remember we're all doing this in our free time and don't get paid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a version that can do well if you just have a few of these diagrams. I define some handy shorthands (only for the diagram) to get also alignment in the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0.2em}
\newcommand{\AU}{\uparrow}
\newcommand{\AD}{\downarrow}
\newcommand{\AR}{\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\AL}{\leftarrow}
\newcommand{\BB}{\bullet}
\begin{array}{*{11}{c}}
    & \AU &     & \AU &     & \AU &     & \AU &     & \AU &     \\
\AR & \BB & \AR & \BB & \AL & \BB & \AL & \BB & \AL & \BB & \AL \\
    & \AU &     & \AD &     & \AU &     & \AU &     & \AU &     \\
\AR & \BB & \AL & \BB & \AR & \BB & \AL & \BB & \AL & \BB & \AL \\
    & \AD &     & \AU &     & \AD &     & \AU &     & \AU &     \\
\AR & \BB & \AR & \BB & \AR & \BB & \AR & \BB & \AL & \BB & \AL \\
    & \AD &     & \AU &     & \AD &     & \AD &     & \AU &     \\
\AR & \BB & \AR & \BB & \AL & \BB & \AR & \BB & \AR & \BB & \AL \\
    & \AD &     & \AU &     & \AD &     & \AD &     & \AU &     \\
\AR & \BB & \AR & \BB & \AR & \BB & \AL & \BB & \AL & \BB & \AL \\
    & \AD &     & \AD &     & \AD &     & \AD &     & \AD &     \\
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

A more refined version, with a new environment, where you just specify the number of vertices per line and also, optionally, a scale factor.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsavebox{\andreabox}
\newenvironment{andrea}[2][1]
 {%
  \newcommand{\andreascale}{#1}%
  \begin{lrbox}{\andreabox}
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0.2em}%
  \newcommand{\AU}{\uparrow}%
  \newcommand{\AD}{\downarrow}%
  \newcommand{\AR}{\rightarrow}%
  \newcommand{\AL}{\leftarrow}%
  \newcommand{\BB}{\bullet}%
  $\begin{array}{*{\numexpr2*#2+1}{c}}%
 }
 {%
  \end{array}$%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \scalebox{\andreascale}{\usebox{\andreabox}}%
 }

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{andrea}{5}
    & \AU &     & \AU &     & \AU &     & \AU &     & \AU &     \\
\AR & \BB & \AR & \BB & \AL & \BB & \AL & \BB & \AL & \BB & \AL \\
    & \AU &     & \AD &     & \AU &     & \AU &     & \AU &     \\
\AR & \BB & \AL & \BB & \AR & \BB & \AL & \BB & \AL & \BB & \AL \\
    & \AD &     & \AU &     & \AD &     & \AU &     & \AU &     \\
\AR & \BB & \AR & \BB & \AR & \BB & \AR & \BB & \AL & \BB & \AL \\
    & \AD &     & \AU &     & \AD &     & \AD &     & \AU &     \\
\AR & \BB & \AR & \BB & \AL & \BB & \AR & \BB & \AR & \BB & \AL \\
    & \AD &     & \AU &     & \AD &     & \AD &     & \AU &     \\
\AR & \BB & \AR & \BB & \AR & \BB & \AL & \BB & \AL & \BB & \AL \\
    & \AD &     & \AD &     & \AD &     & \AD &     & \AD &     \\
\end{andrea}
\]

\[
\begin{andrea}[0.5]{5}
    & \AU &     & \AU &     & \AU &     & \AU &     & \AU &     \\
\AR & \BB & \AR & \BB & \AL & \BB & \AL & \BB & \AL & \BB & \AL \\
    & \AU &     & \AD &     & \AU &     & \AU &     & \AU &     \\
\AR & \BB & \AL & \BB & \AR & \BB & \AL & \BB & \AL & \BB & \AL \\
    & \AD &     & \AU &     & \AD &     & \AU &     & \AU &     \\
\AR & \BB & \AR & \BB & \AR & \BB & \AR & \BB & \AL & \BB & \AL \\
    & \AD &     & \AU &     & \AD &     & \AD &     & \AU &     \\
\AR & \BB & \AR & \BB & \AL & \BB & \AR & \BB & \AR & \BB & \AL \\
    & \AD &     & \AU &     & \AD &     & \AD &     & \AU &     \\
\AR & \BB & \AR & \BB & \AR & \BB & \AL & \BB & \AL & \BB & \AL \\
    & \AD &     & \AD &     & \AD &     & \AD &     & \AD &     \\
\end{andrea}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Lovely to see people helping others.

Comment: @Andrea If you find an answer helpful then please consider to upvote and/or accept the answer. This shows appreciation for the effort.

Comment: How do I do that? Sorry not very familiar with this site!

Comment: @Andrea Use the **arrows and the check mark** that is located left of the answer. It's kind of obvious once you look for it.